# Renaming Angular directives such as *ngFor or custom directives

Tags: angular

We are working on an extension of JS framework that adds on top of Angular.
We are developing our own set of components and API which is more metadata-driven.
The idea is to build our API code in a way that reduces the dependency of the code rewritten to Angular directly to make sure upgrade backward compatibility issue less of a problem.

Therefore, I do not want to directly use Angular specific directives in the code for example: "*ngFor" and instead use something like "*for" instead.

Is that possible at all? can I change the directive page in a config file? or can I write my own directives that work similar to Angular ones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's possible. You can create your own directives that can extend core directives.

For example, in order to use `*for` directive instead of `*ngFor` you can make use of smth like:

```
import { Directive, NgIterable, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { NgForOf } from '@angular/common';

@Directive({
  selector: '[for][forOf]'
})
export class ForDirective<T, U extends NgIterable<T> = NgIterable<T>> 
    extends NgForOf<T, U> {
  @Input()
  set forOf(ngForOf: U&NgIterable<T>|undefined|null) {
    this.ngForOf = ngForOf;
  }
}
```

then in template you're free to write:

```
<div *for="let item of [1,2,3]">{{ item }}</div>
```

**[Ng-run Example](https://ng-run.com/edit/po7FDiaeh9QbVsj7dr1s?open=app%2Fapp.component.html)**